# Parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "howett.net/plist"

Tags: go, go-modules

I'd like to import a Go module which has the following in its `go.mod`:

```
> grep plist go.mod
    github.com/DHowett/go-plist v0.0.0-20180609054337-500bd5b9081b
    howett.net/plist v0.0.0-20181124034731-591f970eefbb // indirect
```

However, if I try to `go get` that package I get the following error message:

```
go: github.com/DHowett/go-plist@v0.0.0-20181124034731-591f970eefbb: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "howett.net/plist"
go get: error loading module requirements
```

I also get this error if I just try to `go get github.com/DHowett/go-plist`:

```
> go get github.com/DHowett/go-plist
go: finding github.com/DHowett/go-plist latest
go: github.com/DHowett/go-plist@v0.0.0-20181124034731-591f970eefbb: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "howett.net/plist"
go: error loading module requirements
```

How can I fix this error so that I can import that module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This module has its identity in [`go.mod`](https://github.com/DHowett/go-plist/blob/master/go.mod) defined as `howett.net/plist` instead of `github.com/DHowett/go-plist`.

If you run this, it should work fine:

```sh
go get howett.net/plist
```

See also [this entry](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-can-i-resolve-parsing-gomod-unexpected-module-path-and-error-loading-module-requirements-errors-caused-by-a-mismatch-between-import-paths-vs-declared-module-identity) in the official Golang Wiki

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by replacing

```golang
import "github.com/DHowett/go-plist
```

everywhere in the module that I wanted to import by

```golang
import "howett.net/plist
```

and running `go mod tidy`. After that, I was able to import it without errors.